# Node modules in qml

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, qt, qml

it's possible to run node modules with qml javascript engine or running js scripts for browsers directly in qml with importing them or in c++ with use of qt QJSEngine class? Thanks ahead of time for any help.

Comment: This looks more like a question you look up in QML documentation rather than ask it here. Moreover it's against the site rules, you should, probably, check out the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @JohnCvelth I think the question is valid, why do you think it does not comply with the SO rules?

Comment: @pbl9 The idea behind `stackoverflow` is to provide a place where community can help solve specific problems. I'd say a good patter of thinking about a good question is "I tried doing X but problems Y and Z rose up, how do I solve them?".

Comment: @pbl9, I think you're going to have a hard time of it.  You can import javascript, but I don't think the engine is ES6-compliant.  It is worth a try on a case-by-case process, but I would guess that giant dependency trees might get you into [dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell)